# Python: how to use merge to perform feature concatenation?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having trouble in performing feature concatenation using pandas.merge.

I have a dataframe that is like:

```
id_A id_B t
  1    2  1
  2    3  0
  3    4  1
...
```

And another dataframe which is like:

```
id f1 f2 f3
 1  1  2  3
 2  4  5  6
 3  7  8  9
 4  8  7  6
 5  5  4  3
...
```

I would like to use pandas.merge or join to create an output that look like this:

```
id_A id_B f1_A f2_A f3_A f1_B f2_B f3_B t
  1    2    1    2    3    4    5    6  1
  2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  0
  3    4    7    8    9    8    7    6  1
...
```

Basically, it's like insert 3 columns of f value from dataframe_2 (based on provided id_A and id_B) into dataframe_1, inbetween id_B and t. But I've failed to do so, after reading tons of documents.

The problem I encountered was, how to use merge to perform this "insert" behaviour? And how is it possible to merge when column names are different in dataframe_1 and 2?

And lastly, from my understanding, you basically need to "search" for id_A in dataframe_2 and add its f1~f3 into dataframe_1, and then "search" for id_B and do the same. How can I do this using merge?

Sorry for my English, also I'm kind of a noob in programming, any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like you should chain the commands. Do one, do second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use double [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) and then join output by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
a = df1[['id_A']].merge(df2.set_index('id').add_suffix('_A'),left_on='id_A', right_index=True)
b = df1[['id_B']].merge(df2.set_index('id').add_suffix('_B'),left_on='id_B', right_index=True)

cols = df1.columns.difference(['id_A','id_B'])
df = pd.concat([a,b, df1[cols]], axis=1)
print (df)
   id_A  f1_A  f2_A  f3_A  id_B  f1_B  f2_B  f3_B  t
0     1     1     2     3     2     4     5     6  1
1     2     4     5     6     3     7     8     9  0
2     3     7     8     9     4     8     7     6  1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! However after I tried to run the code you provided, I got an error that says "KeyError: "['id_A'] not in index"". Do you have any idea what might cause this error? Thanks!

Comment: @MetalheadPrime - `KeyError` means there is no column name `id_A`, you can check columns names by `print (df.columns)`